# Android Add Event to Calendar using Intent, get EventID

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

I'm trying to add event through an calendar intent. However, I can't figure out how to get the event ID of the event just added.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra("beginTime", sdate.getTime());
        intent.putExtra("endTime", edate.getTime());
        intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
        intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
        intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
        intent.putExtra("description", "Description here");
        intent.putExtra("eventLocation", "location here here here");
```

I read extensively on other resources and can't seem to find an answer. I tried startActivityForResult but I can't seem to get it work. Other methods I try can't seem to check for it until the activity ends.

Is there any other way to get the event ID after the event has been added to the calendar? I need to use the intent method for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one solution:

```
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.net.Uri;

public class CalenderUtils {

/**
 * Add a new event into a native Google calendar. Add alert notification by setting <code>isRemind</code> as <code>true</code>.
 * @param cr - ContentResolver
 * @param title - Event title
 * @param addInfo - Event description
 * @param place - Event place
 * @param status -  <code>int</code> This information is sufficient for most entries: tentative (0), confirmed (1) or canceled (2):
 * @param startDate - <code>long</code> event start time in mls
 * @param isRemind - <code>boolean</code> need to remind about event before?
 * @param isMailService - <code>boolean</code>. Adding attendees to the meeting
 * @return <code>long</code> eventID
 */
public static long addEventToCalender(ContentResolver cr, String title, String addInfo, String place, int status,
        long startDate, boolean isRemind, boolean isMailService) {
    String eventUriStr = "content://com.android.calendar/events";
    ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
    // id, We need to choose from our mobile for primary its 1
    event.put("calendar_id", 1); 
    event.put("title", title);
    event.put("description", addInfo);
    event.put("eventLocation", place);
    event.put("eventTimezone", "UTC/GMT +2:00");

    // For next 1hr
    long endDate = startDate + 1000 * 60 * 60; 
    event.put("dtstart", startDate);
    event.put("dtend", endDate);
    //If it is bithday alarm or such kind (which should remind me for whole day) 0 for false, 1 for true
    // values.put("allDay", 1);
    event.put("eventStatus", status);
    event.put("hasAlarm", 1);

    Uri eventUri = cr.insert(Uri.parse(eventUriStr), event);
    long eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());

    if (isRemind) {
        String reminderUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/reminders";
        ContentValues reminderValues = new ContentValues();
        reminderValues.put("event_id", eventID);
        // Default value of the system. Minutes is a integer
        reminderValues.put("minutes", 5); 
        // Alert Methods: Default(0), Alert(1), Email(2), SMS(3)
        reminderValues.put("method", 1); 
        cr.insert(Uri.parse(reminderUriString), reminderValues); //Uri reminderUri = 
    }
    if (isMailService) {
        String attendeuesesUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/attendees";
        /********* To add multiple attendees need to insert ContentValues multiple times ***********/
        ContentValues attendeesValues = new ContentValues();
        attendeesValues.put("event_id", eventID);
        // Attendees name
        attendeesValues.put("attendeeName", "xxxxx");
        // Attendee email
        attendeesValues.put("attendeeEmail", "yyyy@gmail.com");
        // Relationship_Attendee(1), Relationship_None(0), Organizer(2), Performer(3), Speaker(4)
        attendeesValues.put("attendeeRelationship", 0);
        // None(0), Optional(1), Required(2), Resource(3)
        attendeesValues.put("attendeeType", 0);
        // None(0), Accepted(1), Decline(2), Invited(3), Tentative(4)
        attendeesValues.put("attendeeStatus", 0);
        cr.insert(Uri.parse(attendeuesesUriString), attendeesValues); //Uri attendeuesesUri = 
    }

    return eventID;
}

}
```

i copypasted this class from my project so you are welcome to change names as you prefer. 
As you notice here u receive `id` value after insertion.

If you need get `reminderId` or meeting `id` with attendees - you have to handle a return value from `cr.insert...` and then parce uri `long id = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());`

Here is an additional info: [CalendarContract.Events](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html) and [Calendar chapter](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/ics-and-non-public-apis.html)

Comment: Thanks, it's been long since I solved the problem, but this seems to work as well!

Comment: @kotsumu Could you elaborate on your solution? I'm also having this problem. The `onactivityResult` method is not called unless the user cancels the insertion. I can't use the one proposed here since I need to support Gingerbread as well.

Comment: Am I missing the part where you use an intent to generate the calendar event? I belive that was the question.

Comment: how to get event id from calendar query?